# Help identifying cable

Tags: identification

I’m hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.
Im trying to identify this cable as I need to get a longer one.

All help is appreciated
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZeWt.jpg)

Comment: Make it easier for your readers and attract knowledgeable folks by giving more clues in the title. "Help identifying this 54-pin, 0.5 mm pitch flexible PCB-style ribbon cable" and in the post explain what appliance it came out, of, approximate year of manufacture, give further dimensions and state whether it's single or double-sided.

Comment: What about it needs identifying? Which cable it is, or what device uses the cable? Well, it might be a display cable. There's two heavy power buses for something, such as backlight or display supply, as there are two sets of five pins grouped together which might be because of large currents, and there is five sets of differential pairs which could be used for high speed data and clocks. It might be a cable for an LVDS display.

Answer (score 3):

This is not actually a cable, but a flexible PCB (FPC) which is (likely) designed and manufactured for one specific device. Your only chance to get a longer one is probably to reverse engineer the cable and design a longer version of it.

Flex PCBs are not that expensive, so that'd not be unrealistic if a longer version is *really* required.

A dirty solution could also be to simply cut it in half and extend it with ordinary ribbon cable, but that's only acceptable for a hobby project and if you make sure not to change the cables properties too much. For example, I see wide tracks on the FPC, those seem to have low resistance (for high current?).